# Approach to calculating limit via polynomial division

Tags: limits, polynomials

Given the following exercise:
$ \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{3}} (\frac{27x^2-6x-1}{6x^2+x-1}) $

The rule of L'Hospital with the first derivative yields:
$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{3}} \frac{27 x^2 - 6 x - 1}{6 x^2 + x - 1} = \frac{12}{5}$

Another approach would be factoring out the x which also yields:
$\frac{12}{5}$

However, I'm asking myself whether polynomial division, too, could help solving the limit.

Polynomial division yields:
$27 x^2 - 6 x - 1 = \frac{9}{2} \cdot (6 x^2 + x - 1) + \frac{7}{2} - \frac{21x}{2}$

[polynomial division on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomial+division+%2827x%5E2-6x-1%29%2F%286x%5E2%2Bx-1%29)

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so this looks correct. How do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\frac{27x^2-6x-1}{6x^2+x-1}$$

let us compute, using division with increasing powers, the limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(t+\frac 13)$$

$$f(t+\frac 13)=\frac{27t^2+12t}{6t^2+5t}=\frac{27t+12}{6t+5}$$
$$=\frac 15\frac{27t+12}{1+\frac 65t}$$

$$=\frac 15(27t+12)(1-\frac 65t+o(t))$$

so the limit is $ \frac{12}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  To use polynomial division, I would first write (for $x \neq \frac13$):
$$\frac{27x^2-6x-1}{6x^2+x-1} = \frac92 - \frac7{2(2x+1)}$$

Now taking the limit is trivial...